# Bootstrap modal in Rails 4 doesn't pop up

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the example to write a rails app with a modal pop up .

[Heroku Demo link](http://protected-atoll-9873.herokuapp.com/people)

This is code i have (quite a few lines)

```
index.html.erb
<h1>Listing people</h1>
<%= link_to 'Add Person Modal', new_test_path,  
 {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade in" role="dialog"
 aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; "></div>

_new_test.html.erb
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  **here comes whatever you want to show!**
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>



people_controller.rb
 def new_test
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.js
  end
 end

 new_test.js.erb
// $("modal-window").modal();
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'people/new_test') %>");
```

Any Help appreciated !!

Comment: Looks like you're missing some dependencies. At a minimum, I don't see where you included the Bootstrap CSS (it doesn't appear to be part of the CSS bundle).

Comment: Ah ,ok i added the css not .Now on click i see the screen fades in but modal doesnt display. I updated the heroku link too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As an alternative**, if you need the ability to have varying content in the modal, I'd suggest using [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/) instead; it generates the modal markup on the fly, and can be used as alternatives to the default confirm/prompt/alert browser dialogs. The advantage of using generated markup is that you don't have to deal with resetting the template that the modal normally requires.

Here's a sample derived from a recent project of mine:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" data-modal-href="remote.html" class="show-modal">Click me</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.show-modal', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).data('modal-href');

    $.get(url)
        .fail(function () {
            bootbox
                .alert("<b>We're sorry.</b> The modal could not be loaded. Please wait a moment and then try again.", function () {
                })
                .find('div.modal-dialog')
                .addClass('modal-sm');
        })
        .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {
            bootbox.dialog({
                show: true,
                title: 'Your Modal Title',
                message: response,
                buttons: {
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'Cancel',
                        className: 'btn'
                    },
                    save: {
                        label: 'Save',
                        className: 'btn btn-primary',
                        callback: function() { /* your 'save' callback */ }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
});
```

`message` is the option used to fill in the `.modal-body` portion of the generated modal. This is a naive implementation, though, as it doesn't include any checks to verify that you're not getting, say, a complete HTML page back in `response`.

I also normally include a loading animation prior to executing the `$.get` function, but that's something I think you can figure out on your own.

Comment: [Remote modals are being deprecated](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14034), so I would recommend implementing the external content loading yourself instead.

Comment: @harshit Based on cvrebert's comment for the linked Bootstrap issue, I'm going to edit the answer to show how to use Bootbox.js (which leverages the Bootstrap modal plugin) to load remote content; I think that will be easier to implement than using the modals directly.